# Accidentally deleted most recent migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I made the clumsiest mistake. When I went to highlight a migration file's name in my text editor, my finger slipped and I deleted that migration file. The schema already has the migration file's table schema, but how do I restore the file I just deleted? I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656042/restore-a-migration-after-manually-deleting-it-in-database) post, but it did not help me.

I've been blowing through some work so I did not commit and cannot reclaim the lost file via version control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this solved my problem. I wrote, `git diff`, in terminal where was printed the name of the file I deleted: 20151014152222_create_post_categories.rb

I just recreated this file with the appropriate migration code in it. Originally I wanted to rename the table to, posts_categories, so after running `rake db migrate`, I ran, `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20151014152222`, renamed the file and the first argument to, create_table, with :posts_categories.

Then I just ran the migrations again. This obviously brought back the missing file and correctly edited my schema.